# OWIN WS-FED Passive signout of identity provider

Tags: owin, katana, ws-federation

So I have a solution that is using Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation 3.0.0-rc2 and I'm trying to get Passive sign-out calling back to the identity provider to log out of there as well as my application (so I don't get a redirect loop just logging it back in).

I'm currently using WAAD as the WS-Fed endpoint.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/login")
});

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
    AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WSFEDRealm"],
    MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WSFEDMetadataAddress"]
});
```

I can get it working fine if I use active but it would be nice to have the option of using passive as well.

I am signing out using:

```
_authenticationManager.SignOut();
```

I think it has something to do with these lines in the signout helper

```
if (revoke.AuthenticationTypes == null || revoke.AuthenticationTypes.Length == 0)
{
    return authenticationMode == AuthenticationMode.Active ? revoke : null;
}
```

But I'm unsure of how I add to the revoke.AuthenticationTypes dictionary?

Comment: to add an `authenticationType` to the `revoke.AuthenticationTypes` collection you should call `_authenticationManager.SignOut` with that `authenticationType` in parameter for example:
if you call `_authenticationManager.SignOut("ExternalCookie")`
then you will have "ExternalCookie" in the `revoke.AuthenticationTypes` collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential solution is to manually force the signout1.0 request

```
var wsConfiguration = await _wsConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Request.CallCancelled);
var message = new WsFederationMessage
{
    IssuerAddress = wsConfiguration.TokenEndpoint,
    Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WSFEDRealm"],
    Wreply = Url.Action("Index", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme),
    Wa = "wsignout1.0"
};
```

I then have a binding in my ninject module for the wsfederation configuration

```
Bind<IConfigurationManager<WsFederationConfiguration>>().ToMethod((c) =>
{
    var owinContext = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        return new ConfigurationManager<WsFederationConfiguration>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WSFEDMetadataAddress"]);
}).InSingletonScope();
```

I'm not 100% happy with this solution as it means there are two running configuration managers for the metadata, but it is a working solution.